# I use string.split("|") and I am getting array that have every char in one array element

Tags: java

My code:

```
  result ="sub||hi";
  String[] results = result.split("||");
```

I want:

```
results [0]=sub
results [1]=hi
```

But I get:

```
result[0]=s
result[1]=u
result[2]=b
result[3]=h
result[4]=s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `|` properly:

```
String[] results = result.split("\\|");
```

An alternative is to use `Pattern`:

```
String[] results = result.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
```

Answer (score 12):

Use

```
String[] results = result.split("\\|");
```

Comment: ...because `split()` takes a regular expression, and `|` is a special character in regular expressions.

Answer (score 5):

Note that [public String[] split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a **regex**.

You need to escape the [special char](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) `|`.
Escaping a regex is done by `\`, but in Java, `\` is written as `\\`.

**Alternative solution** that is good to mention:

You can use [public static String quote(String s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) that "*Returns a literal pattern String for the specified String*":

`String[] result = result.split(Pattern.quote("|"));`

Now, `|` will be treated as the **character** `|` and not as the regex `|` with the special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Since `|` is a meta character,It works when you escape the special character.

```
String[] results = result.split("\\|");
```

[Related Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/names/syntax.html)